# Couln't find or load main class after renaming main class?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, maven-2

I have renamed my main class from CarInsurance to CarInsuranceQuote and I am getting "could not find or load main class" error when i run jar file.
I am using Netbeans 8.2 and maven as build tool. Here is pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.challenge</groupId>
    <artifactId>CarInsurance</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.challenge.carinsurance.CarInsuranceQuote</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Any help is appreciated, as I am stuck, I have restarted netbeans, 
done mvn clean before compiling but still getting same error.

Comment: you packaged? or just compiled?

Comment: @Vitaliy Moskalyuk just compiled

Comment: so your jar was not changed, and you executing old jar

Comment: @Vitaliy Moskalyuk, could you please write out mvn commands to follow (steps), as I am new to maven. Thanks

Comment: try at least `mvn package`. Here is doc https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: @Vitaliy Moskalyuk I can see build success after running mvn package, but when i run jar file (java -jar CarInsurance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) from target folder I am still getting could not find or load main class.

Comment: try `maven clean install` and start jar. 
Some  another question - what for you execute jar? Looks like this is automation project)

Comment: @Vitaliy Moskalyuk, I have already done mvn clean install, but still getting same error, yes its automation project, which opens a web-page and fill in some text boxes and click few buttons. Many Thanks. but my problem isn't solved yet.

Comment: and run jar that will be created after build in target dir, not some pre-saved jar -)

Comment: is this correct path to main class  `com.challenge.carinsurance.CarInsuranceQuote`? package was not renamed? sorry for silly questions, but issue could be anywhere)

Comment: yes its correct project structure.

Comment: Project structure looks like:
CarInsurance

|----com.challenge.carinsurance (package)
       |----CarInsuranceQuote.java

Comment: If you want fat jar with all deps go for mvn-assembly-plugin